# confluent-zookeeper not found

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I tried installing confluent in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver LTS using the below link:

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html

But i am unable to find the zookeeper and kafka service that i require along with other components.

Could anyone guide me on how and where to find and install these components as well?

Comment: Why can't you just install `confluent-platform` package? It includes Kafka and Zookeeper

Comment: Hello....I am actually trying out installation via terminal for educational purpose.

Comment: Right... `apt install confluent-platform` like that documentation says. Nowhere does it mention installing Zookeeper and Kafka separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the list of individual packages here

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/available_packages.html#component-packages

There is no individual `confluent-zookeeper` package. That Systemd service gets installed alongside `confluent-platform` or `confluent-kafka` packages

Comment: I dug deeper to the problem and found that the system was not allowing certain packages to install......i did a force install for the packages and now i happen to see them as they were intended to be. Thank you for your help here!!!!